# Warnings in Eclipse IDE after import a JHipster project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jhipster

I am a beginner developer trying to create my first project using Jhipster. I am trying to set up everything to start coding in the most accurate environment in order to avoid further problems or warning in the future.

I have imported the new project to the Eclipse IDE following the instructions in jHipster web, but as you can see in the picture, some warnings appear:

[image: Warning in Eclipse IDE after import jHipster project]

Is there something important that I have to worry about? If yes, how can I solve it?

I can solve the first one, but I am not sure if I solve it in the right way. I did not find any solution related to the other ones.

Comment: You could google each of those warnings, find out what they mean, decide whether you need to do something about them and then either ignore or resolve them.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something important that I have to worry about? If yes, how can I solve it?

Warnings are not high priority problems, they will not break your application. That said fixing them is never a bad idea, I personally like to keep my projects clean.

Most of the Java problems you have are for unused imports or variables, remove them from your code and the warnings will disappear. You can double click on each warning and eclipse will take you right to the line of code.

For the `serialVersionUID` problems you can just click on the yellow light bulb left of the line number and then click `Add default serial version ID`.

The first two problems you say you can fix them, good. They are telling you there is a mismatch between the expected Java version and the one used. One way to fix them is to install the 1.8 JDK (get it from [here](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)) and set it as your default JRE (`Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs`).